# DIV side by side, incorrect positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried so many different ways trying to get 2 div's staying side by side, but no matter what I do I can't seem to figure it out.

I managed to sort it for a while with "position: absolute" but that was until I realized the menu hight wasn't changing. I'm not an expert when it comes to CSS but the rest I'm good at. I've searched and search and so far this is the best results I've came up with:

Results like this: http://puu.sh/oWRbK/4827eeba57.jpg but should looks like this: http://puu.sh/oWS52/a2dc6282e4.jpg anyone that has any suggestions how to fix this issue, please feel free helping me as I'm getting gray haired by this right now, been trying to figure out a way for the past 4 hours but no matter what I do, if I margin-top the pixels space I get it correct but in a different resolution comparing to my monitor messes it completely up.

```css
.wrapper {
    padding-left: 68px;
    padding-right: 68px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
}

.header {
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
}

.hline {
    width:auto; 
    height:2px; 
    background: #FFFFFF; 
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

#contentwrapper{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#contentcolumn{
    margin-left: 325px;
}

/* USER MENU */

.menuWrap {
    padding-right: 65px;
    width: 260px;
}

.user_menu {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-top: 41px;
    min-height: 390px;
    width: 260px;
    color: #a6bed5;
    background: rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.5); /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.5), rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.5)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.5), rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.5)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.5), rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.5)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.5), rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.5)); /* Standard syntax */
}

.user_after {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    height: 39px;
    width: 260px;
    background: #6e6e6e; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #6e6e6e, #ebebeb); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #6e6e6e, #ebebeb); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #6e6e6e, #ebebeb); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #6e6e6e, #ebebeb); /* Standard syntax */
    opacity: 0.3;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.user_menu .content {
    width: 260px;
}

.user_menu .header {
    padding: 6px;
    border-bottom: 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) solid;
    min-height: 62px;
}

.user_menu .header img {
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    float: left;
}

.user_menu .header p {
    padding-left: 70px;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.user_menu .header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #94a9b9;
}

.user_menu .header a:link a:visited a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #94a9b9;
}

.user_menu .header a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #b5cee6;
}

.user_menu .addMenu {
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.user_menu .addMenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.user_menu .addMenu li a {
    display: block;
    color: #94a9b9;
    padding: 12px 0 12px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) solid;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
.user_menu .addMenu li a:hover {
    color: #b5cee6;
}

/* MAIN CONTAINER */

.bs-container {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-top: 41px;
    min-height: 390px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <img src="/images/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="hline"></div>

        <div id="contentwrapper">
            <div id="contentcolumn">
                <div class="bs-container">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2"><!--ISSUE IS RIGHT HERE.-->
            <div class="user_menu">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="header">
                        <img src="http://mta.everest-community.net/mta-image.php?id=1" />
                        <p>
                            <b><font color="#f7b618">123B3n</font> <font color="#334c66">(1)</font></b><br>
                            <a href="#">LOGOUT</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="addMenu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#characters">CHARACTERS <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="false"></i></a></li>
                            <div id="characters" class="collapse">
                                <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 40px;">OVERVIEW</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 40px;">STAT TRANSFER</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 40px;">CUSTOM INTERIORS</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 40px;">MANAGEMENT</a></li>
                            </div>
                            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#account">ACCOUNT <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="false"></i></a></li>
                            <div id="account" class="collapse">
                                <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 40px;">PROFILE</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 40px;">HISTORY</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 40px;">SETTINGS</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 40px;">OVERVIEW</a></li>
                            </div>
                            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#premium">PREMIUM <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="false"></i></a></li>
                            <div id="premium" class="collapse">
                                <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 40px;">PREMIUM FEATURES</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 40px;">DONATION HISTORY</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 40px;">DONATE NOW!</a></li>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="user_after"></div><!--JUST FOR SHOW-->
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/123B3n/ohku4a0q/

P.S Didn't know about JSFiddle until now, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: your issue is `#contentwrapper{ float: left; width: 100%; }`. Also put your code in JSfiddle to expect for further attention from users, people dont like to look at longer code like this.

Comment: I don't think it's correct html to have divs inside a <ul> amongst <li> tags

Comment: Eddie is correct (below answer) - you are using Bootstrap but not using it. Best to do a tutorial on Bootstrap - [this one](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/tutorial.php) goes pretty quick. *The main point of bootstrap is the grid system*

Comment: To easily have one div beside the other, just give them "display: inline-block". As long as their widths/margins are not larger than the width of the screen, they should go beside each other.

Answer (score 2):

You are providing your CSS, but you are also using Bootstrap in your code (or what looks like it) and I am wondering if you have thought about the impact.

```
--> row
 ---->col-md-2
```

That is using the two column grid of a 12 column system with the md breakpoint, where is the other `col-md-10` for the right side.

To me, it looks like you are in a losing battle with bootstrap. And without the full code, the only solution here is to rewrite all of your code and that actualyl does you no service.

I will give you this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">Left</div>
<div class="col-md-10">Right</div>
</div>
```

12 Column system, but then you need to look into what happens when you go mobile and get smaller than the md breakpoint.

That *MAY* be as simple as

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">Left</div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried as you suggested but that ends me up with the same issue as I had before which was the second column that is now correct, for some reason everytime I try to get two divs side by side it always ends bad and I drop the project instead. I can't seem to get both of the correct however one of them, problem getting them correct last time was that they where either overlapping or I couldn't get the width correct on the second column as it's using "width: auto/100%" for it's correct size.

Answer (score 0):

How's this? https://jsfiddle.net/wx3emp71/2/

I reorganized your row div to contain both of the columns you want beside each other. Then I gave them a class of "content" (feel free to change that) and made them inline-blocks of 50% width each. I also removed some margin you had on one of your containers. To make them display beside each other at 50% width, I had to restructure your divs a little bit so that there's no white space between the end of the close tag and the beginning of the new open tag. Lastly, I gave them `box-sizing: border-box` just so that any margins/padding don't come into play when calculating the width, therefore allowing the 50% width to work.

If you like my solution, I actually recommend you add the following style, `*{ box-sizing: border-box;}` to all your CSS files. That way, everything has the border-box property and you never have to worry about fitting the paddings into your calculations.

I put my work under the /***** my edit *****/ comment so you can change it however you feel fit. I don't think I added any other styling elsewhere, but I did remove some as I mentioned before.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you don't want 50%/50%. Working on it.

Comment: Ok here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/wx3emp71/2/ I think this is what you're after, right? You'll need media queries for this to make more sense on various screen sizes. Just change the percentage widths. You could also give your row div a max width so that it doesn't become too large. Please note I deleted some widths you had for some elements.

Comment: Wow, really thanks man! now their side by side force once :) the main problem now is that their overlapping for me on a lower resolution then 1080 as well as the size is very much off. I kinda managed to get it some what as close as you wrote it but not as good. But the size always messes up as well as the overlapping part. It looks fine in JSFiddle but once on a actual html page it messes up like this, not sure how to resolve it unfortunately [link](http://puu.sh/oWYSs/4fd2a53824.jpg) But really thanks man! :)

Comment: That's odd how the second container isn't going to the right. Maybe you added a margin, or a max width to the row? You'll probably have to mess around with media queries to get this to work at all sizes.

Comment: It seems to be fine in my browser. Did you make any changes? http://imgur.com/1QaM2Eq

Comment: I copied all of it over that's it, works perfect on JSFiddle but not on own website for some reason http://a3l.everest-community.net/temp.html